# SRAM X01 derailleur very slow to shift into two smallest cogs

Tags: derailleur-rear, shifting

I recently changed bikes and have my first SRAM derailleur.  I'm relatively new to bikes (couple of years) but mechanically handy, and had no issues adjusting the Shimano XT derailleur on my last bike.  This SRAM X01 has me stumped though - I *cannot* get it to work properly no matter how many times I adjust it.

I'm following the process that's worked for me for the last year or two:

1. Check hanger alignment
2. Set H screw
3. Set indexing
4. Set L screw
5. Set B-tension
6. If b-tension took a significant adjustment, repeat 2-4

I can get this bike to shift across the cassette ok, but when it gets back to the third smallest cog it is very slow to drop to the 2nd and smallest from there.  If I double-shift it'll get all the way down most of the time, but if I shift one at a time it's about four to six full cranks before it shifts.  It does this in the stand **and** under power.

If I introduce enough slack so it won't shift from the smallest to the second cog properly, **and** back the H screw out so far that it no longer contacts the derailleur at all (placing the upper jockey wheel teeth about 3mm outboard of the smallest cog), it STILL doesn't want to shift into the smallest cog easily.

If I undo the cable retainer completely, push the derailleur with my hands and pedal til it moves up a few gears, then let it go... it stops at the second smallest gear most of the time.

The shifter paddle feels dull moving into the smaller gears.. there's a tactile 'click' to each shift as I go from largest to smallest, but these ones barely click and the sound even changes a bit, like there is little to no tension on the cable by this stage.

The system is just under six months old and has done about 700km.

I'm not sure what to do from here, any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have had this problem with various SRAM and frame/wheel combinations, especially on the original road lineup. I haven't come accross the problem recently, but you can still use the same fix.

If you put an M10 washer on the derailleur's main bolt (between the hanger and the derailleur) you will gain about 1mm extra movement outboard, which should be enough to solve the problem. The B set screw will still be aligned fully on the tab and there aren't any other pitfalls. I would avoid stacking more than 1.5mm.

I believe your derailleur is at the limit of its movement due to the internal spring either being too weak or too long for your frame combo.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  The spring being too weak is exactly how it *feels,* both through the shift paddle and at the derailleur... like it's not pulling the chain hard enough to skip it off the bigger gear.

I found the washer solution in another discussion, but nobody sounded very confident about it so I'm glad to hear from someone who's tried it before.  Will give it a crack and report back.  Cheers